# Is there a way to get user input in terminal after npm start?

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal

Say I have a simple program that keeps running in the background. Here is a barebones simulation (`index.js`).

```
process.stdin.resume();
console.log('just hanging...')
```

Then run it with `node index.js` and there, nothing else happens till we just exit `ctrl+c`

However, you could still type in the terminal. Nothing actually happens but you are able to type.

Without propts can we read the input in our node project? A bit like in a textfield with font-end JavaScript?

Comment: Maybe you say something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt 

https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/command-line/how-to-prompt-for-command-line-input/

Comment: @fedeteka no that's not what I am after, I just found out how to get what I want and wrote the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
process.stdin.on('data',function(data){
    var entry = data.toString() 
    console.log(entry)

})
```

So as the process is running you're able to type into the terminal and once you hit enter, you can catch it as above `data.toString()` (of course the string itself captures the new line as well so it with `\n` at the end.

Whilst searching this I also learned that you can use the same idea instead of console.log

```
process.stdout.write(entry)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your browser and inspect element, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> in chrome. From there there is a console tab which you can use to see the output value